# How to get the recovered memory references in IDA-Pro?

Tags: ida, idapython, symbols

I want to collect all the IDA recovered symbol information in data sections (this information could be **function name**, or it could be **an entry of jump table**, or it could be a **reference to other data sections**).

Here is an example of data sections from a IDA disassembled binary.

[image]

Basically there are three recovered symbols in data section, and I want to collect these information in a format like this:

```
0x804a018 : sub_804847b
0x804a01dc : _strchr
0x804a020 : sub_80484AE
```

I am thinking to traverse all the memory address of a binary's data sections, and check the content of each address, to see whether it is a recovered symbol.

But basically how to read a suspicious symbol when iterating addresses? I read the [`idc`](https://www.hex-rays.com/products/ida/support/idadoc/162.shtml) interface, but I just cannot find any the correct api to do so. Could anyone help me on this issue? I appreciate that.

------------------------ explain ------------------------

I didn't get an answer in that post, in addition, I think what I explained in that post is somehow misleading.

Comment: It can also be a **random sequence of binary numbers** instead of an address. The only numbers that should be converted to an actual address are those listed in the relocation table.

Comment: @JasonGeffner, hi Jason, firstly, my question is still not be answered in that post. Secondly, I am worried that post contains much more stuff that can mislead other people. Anyway, any though on this issue? :)

Comment: @Jongware, thank you and I know it could be. So you mean the symbolized memory references are already listed in `relocation table`, does IDA-Pro collects this information?

Comment: If they are present in the executable, then it should be aware: my free-demo version shows a comment such as `OFF32 SEGDEF [CODE,524A0612]` for undefined bytes that are relocated, but it does not complain if I define them otherwise. I'm not sure if one can interrogate the relocation table through IDA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understood your question, you will need the following IDAPython apis:

- Getting a content from specific memory address : idc.Dword(address) or idc.Qword(address) - you should choose the function according to the pointer size.
- Obtaining a name of the address: idc.Name(address)

All the mentioned IDAPython apis has the similar things in idc

So, for your specific example you'll get the desired output as follows (IDAPython):

```
import idc
addresses = [0x804a018, 0x804a01dc ,0x804a020 ]

for a in addresses:
    print hex(a)," : ", idc.Name(idc.Dword(a))
```

Filtering the data in the .data section is completely different story.

For example you can do the following (it is not 100% correct):

```
import idc

segstart = your_code_segment_start
segend = your_code_segment_end
ptrstep = your_system_pointer_size_in_bytes

for a in range(segstart, segend, ptrstep):
    data = idc.Dword(a) #replace with qword if working with 64 bit)
    if a < segstart or a >= segend:
        continue
    if not idc.Name(data) is None:
        print hex(a), " --> ", idc.Name(data)
```

Comment: Thank you! I also updated some code [here](http://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/a/8627/3215).